# Yellowing lower tomato leaves

Tags: tomatoes

What is wrong with these plants? I’m moving in a month so can’t put them in the ground yet. The bottom leaves are turning yellow and starting to get brown spots.

I don’t know if I’m watering too much or not enough, or maybe the soil is compacted, fungus???
Help! What should I do?

Thanks!
Steve

[image][image][image][image]

Comment: Could be nitrogen deficiency - have you fed them at all yet?

Comment: Ive been using Neptune’s harvest liquid once a week.

Comment: What is the formula on that product?

Comment: Found it I believe; 2 - 3 - 1.  Very light but still balanced and you give this to THESE plants once per week?  Now I am stumped...what soil did you use in these pots.  What is the difference between the plant in the black pot versus the plastic terra cotta colored pots?  When we discover the difference between these pots that will be the answer I am thinking and hoping.  What is different, do you know?  Did you put any gravel or rock below the soil and above the drain hole?  They all have drain holes, right?  Same soil?  Potting soil?  No compost added?  Looks like potting soil...more info!

Comment: The terracotta colored plastic pots (one or two pots)? the plants look lacking in Phosphorus, Nitrogen.  The plant in the black pot is almost perfect in coloring...still a little light in Nitrogen, you've got flowers, the camera may not be showing true color.  Need to figure out what is different between these plants.  Tell us anything at all you've done.  Anything no matter how seemingly insignificant the information, please tell us.

Comment: And your plants will be fine by the time you move.  Where are you moving?  Uhaul for the plants, yes?  How long will the trip be?

Comment: Just another tip: Get just grass clippings as mulch down on that soil to prevent any potential fungi from splashing up on the lower leaves.  That is my biggest pitfall with tomatoes.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I used the same miracle grow potting soil in all of the pots, and fed them all together.  I didn't put rocks in--should I have?  They all have drain holes, but perhaps there are less in the terracotta pots?

Comment: I wonder if your plants are getting too much sodium.

Comment: What are your temperatures? The plant shows signs of phosphorus deficiency, which it shouldn't if you're using pre-fertilized soil and adding fertilizer—unless it's cold. The leaves also look like sulfur deficient leaves (although sulfur is an immobile nutrient; so, it should be on the new growth instead).

Comment: I live in central MA, so it was getting down into the low 50s, maybe just below 50 some nights they were outside.  They were very purple when they were seedlings indoors, but the purple seemed to go away when I put them in bigger pots and got them outside.